# meta tag description does not show when viewing source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, heroku, meta-tags, erb

i use this code to show description tag and keyword

```
<meta name="description" content="search thousands of humor, funny images<%= yield :description %>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="funny, fun, comics, jokes, images, pictures, photos, humor, safe for work<%= yield :keywords %>" />
```

but it dose not show in the production environment while showing in development environment 
my production environment is rails 3.2.11 and heroku so did i miss something ? i even tried this code

```
<meta name="keywords" content="funny, fun, comics, jokes, images, pictures, photos, humor, safe for work" />
```

and it's the same result so what i am missing guys ? i really started to freak out !!

Comment: Are you sure this HTML in your layout has been committed into your git repository and deployed to heroku **successfully**?

Comment: yes what makes me going crazy even more http://www.funii.com/images/comic/the-secret-pocket in this url it dose not work and in this url it's worked http://www.funii.com/images/comic/--583 it's the same code !!

Comment: solved i used http://html5.validator.nu/ and there was some html errors and i solve html error then upload to heroku and the meta tag problem solved automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved i used html5.validator.nu and there was some html errors and i solve html error then upload to heroku and the meta tag problem solved automatically